# What is in Meghan's box in Felicity?

Tags: plot-explanation, felicity

For the whole of the first season in Felicity, Meghan (Felicity's room-mate) keeps on telling her to not look in her box. I know that it is something shocking because when Meghan's parents come to visit and Meghan pretends that the box is Felicity's and they look in it they are shocked and worried about Felicity being Meghan's room-mate.

So at any point do we find out what is in the box?

Answer (score 8):

[Sort of](http://www.avoidingregret.com/2009/05/what-i-learned-from-felicity.html) -- beware, spoilers for S02E11:

> Felicity's freshman year roommate Meghan had a mysterious box,
>   literally. She would rebuff anyone who asked her about it, looked at
>   it, or dared think of touching it. When we finally found out what was
>   actually in the box [SPOILER ALERT], it was kind of disappointing, but
>   freaky in a way that foreshadowed J.J. Abrams' future career: **the
>   "Twilight Zone" episode revealed that Meghan actually kept Felicity,
>   Ben, and Noel in the box and was orchestrating their every move like a
>   puppetmaster.**

On a more serious note: I don't think it has ever been revealed.

[Amanda Foreman (Meghan) didn't know](http://www.angelfire.com/ego/felicity/wandachat.htm):

> From liddymack: Amanda, what was in Meghan's box?
>
> Amanda: **They never told me what was in it**, but I thought it could be a
>   confession to a murder. If you look back, there are very few things it
>   could be. I thought maybe it was a false confession, and that's why my
>   dad freaked out. I heard people saying it was a dead baby. I thought
>   that was a little gross and over-the-top.

In that same conversation, JJ dodges the question:

> From Kim: JJ, what was in Meghan's mystery box? Make something up if
>   you have to.
>
> JJ: We sort of dealt with that in our Twilight Zone homage in an
>   episode titled "Help for the Lovelorn." The prop itself is in my
>   office--**I have yet to look myself.**

Comment: That is just mean of JJ.!  He has to tell us!! :)

Comment: I always theorized that it was the bones of Pickles, Megan's childhood dog. Sometimes in pop culture Wiccan or Neo Paganism depicts rituals and spells involving animals. (My friend is a Wiccan and she actually does carry a cat's tooth bone necklace). Some collect bones for cleansing/healing practices. It just always struck me, how Megan showed her humanity, with the reveal of having a pet dog. I guess we'll never know for sure though!